# Using an email address with two different names in Gmail? (as two aliases)

Tags: gmail

I've setup Gmail to use my own email address, like `info@mycompany.com`. When using this address as from-address, sometimes I want it to prefix with my personal name, and sometimes my company name. I mean the possibility to use either: `John Doe <info@mycompany.com>` or `Acme Inc <info@mycompany.com>`. Same from-address, but prefixed with a different name.

However, if I add one (in Accounts and Imports) and then add the other, it says: address already exists. Yes, that's right, but I want to use the same address with different names.

How do I go about this, or is this impossible in Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use "plus addresses" and you domain name (e.g. mycompany.com) supports it (like gmail.com does) you can mostly fake it.

Add a new "send as" address with Name of "Agent Black" and email address of "yourgmail+agentblack@gmail.com".

When receiving mail Google will ignore everything between the + and the @.

Comment: I'm familiar with plus addresses, but in this case I need both addresses to be the same (just with different names in the From: header).

Answer (score -2):

It impossible to do it in gmail, but you can delete this address and add it with the wanted name.

Comment: That would be pretty extreme. One can easily change the alias of an email address within Gmail; there is no need to delete a whole account just to change an alias. The OP is dealing with what is technically the same address.