# Can you have two different names for the same alternative ("send mail as") email address in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I can add `me@mydomain.com` under "send mail as" email address in Gmail settings.

But can I choose between two different names to use with it, like I can in e.g. Mac Mail?

For instance, can I set it up so when emailing I have the choice between sending mail as either `Bob <me@mydomain.com>` or `Agent Black <me@mydomain.com>`?

Comment: Same question was asked yesterday: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86355/using-an-email-adress-with-two-different-names-in-gmail-as-two-aliases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

However, if you're willing to use "plus addresses" you can mostly fake it.

Add a new "send as" address with Name of "Agent Black" and email address of "tog22+agentblack@gmail.com". (Obviously you'd use your own email address.)

When receiving mail Google will ignore everything between the `+` and the `@`.

I used to do the same when my kids were little to fake mail to and from their grandparents.

Comment: In addition, you could set the same "Reply-To" for both.